# HttpPost request unsuccessful

Tags: java, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have written a web service and am now writing a tester to perform integration testing from the outside. I am writing my tester using apache httpclient 4.3. Based on the code here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/quickstart.html and here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e186 I have written the following code.

```
    Map<String, String> parms = new HashMap<>();
    parms.put(AirController.KEY_VALUE, json);
    postUrl(SERVLET, parms);
    ...

protected String postUrl(String servletName, Map<String, String> parms)
        throws AirException{
    String url = rootUrl + servletName;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry:parms.entrySet()){
        BasicNameValuePair parm = new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        nvps.add(parm);
    }

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException use) {
        String msg = "Invalid parameters:" + parms;
        throw new AirException(msg, use);
    }

    CloseableHttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(post);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new AirException(ioe);
    }

    String result;
    if(HttpStatus.SC_OK == response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()){
        result = processResponse(response);
    }
    else{
        String msg = MessageFormat.format("Invalid status code {0} received from query {1}.",
                                            new Object[]{response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), url});
        throw new AirException(msg);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This code successfully reaches my servlet. In my servlet, I have (using Spring's AbstractController):

```
protected ModelAndView post(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String json = String.valueOf(request.getParameter(KEY_VALUE));
    if(json.equals("null")){
        log.info("Received null value.");
        response.setStatus(406);
        return null;
    }
```

And this code always falls into the null parameter code and returns a 406.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but can't see what it is.

Comment: What does `parms` contain?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Look at the first few lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, but what value does `json` have? Does `AirController.KEY_VALUE` have the same value as `KEY_VALUE` in the controller?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis json has a JSON serialized object with lots of stuff in it. Yes, the KEY_VALUE items are the same object.

Comment: Add some details. Is the log message printed? You should be able to register an Http `Filter` or `Interceptor` which gives you access to the bytes written to the HTTP request. You could check what is serialized.

Answer (score 0):

dont see how debugging this is possible without dumping the headers?

```
  post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
```

Dont you have to know what headers result from the above?
Dont you have to know exactly the collection of headers being marshalled by your code?

You could test with curl/wget as the client to your service first, using verbose to be sure exactly the set of headers you are using in sucessful posts to your service.

Then, just get close to  that set of headers with your java client and you should be good.

For example, which stuff does your java client need to set with a RequestInterceptor implementation ?

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()     .setConnectionManager(YourConnectionMgr.getInstance())
.addInterceptorLast(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
    public void process(
    final HttpRequest request, 
final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException { 
..
                                        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json") ;
                                        request.addHeader("Content-Type", mimeType) ;
                                    request.removeHeaders("Accept-Encoding");
                                    request.removeHeaders("Content-Type");
                                    request.addHeader("Expect", "100-continue");
                                    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8") ;
```

To get the headers right will probably resolve your server side issue but you will need to expose the headers and maybe even expose the WIRE level logger.